# Is there somewhere else to buy the Remembrance Weapons?

Tags: elden-ring

I burnt the tree and now the finger reader in roundtable hold won't speak to me (understandable I guess) but I want to trade in some remembrances.

Is there any other way I can get them traded for weapons or is that it now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finger Reader Enia is the only NPC who you can trade Remembrances with.

After burning the Erdtree, she will become unresponsive (I believe she's dead), but her shop should still remain accessible. Simply interact with her body to access her shop like normal.

There's another NPC whose shop remains accessible in the same way even after death:

> Seluvis' puppet shop.

Comment: That is quite morbid.

Comment: @TimmyJim, I agree. Then again, Elden Ring is full of morbidity.

Comment: Thanks when i first tried to speak to her it said 'she's unresponsive' but i went away and came back and spoke to her again and she said something like 'heh you ask me to continue working after all you have done, well if you feel what you've done is right' and then she's as per normal, so not quite dead but you did make me try and talk to her again which got me the result i wanted so i'll mark it as correct as in just go and talk to her again does work :D